# Can I uninstall UFW completely?

Tags: server, ufw

I need to configure iptables manually and save and restore the rules using `iptables-persistent` package. so I don't want ufw anymore.

I can simply disable it. but many chains are exists in iptables rules dump, and I do not want to see them.

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [593:73026]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [449:94341]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Mar 30 07:26:41 2013
```

But I just need to know, can I completely uninstall UFW or not ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you can remove or disable `ufw` and/or `gufw` without any problem. It will not affect your `iptables` configuration. UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) was simply developed to ease some configurations done with iptables.

Removing it will not affect your `iptables` configuration.

To disable UFW you can type the following:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

To remove it you can type the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove ufw
```

To purge it (In those cases where you really hate ufw or wasting space) you can type the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge ufw
```

The only thing you **can not do** is remove `iptables`. This is because it is a dependency package of `ufw`, therefore `ufw` depends on `iptables` (Not the other way around ^^).

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. After command

```
iptables -L
```

I saw remians of ufw.

Just use two commands:

```
iptables -F

iptables -Z
```

-F is for flush

-Z is for zero chains

Comment: But what happens after enable and-or disabling ufw?

Comment: I had to delete ufw from my system. Those two commands only clean remains of ufw in my listing of iptables.

Comment: yes, you have to flush the tables or reboot the box

Answer (score 0):

To replace UFW with native iptables:

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo apt-get remove ufw
sudo apt-get purge ufw
sudo apt install iptables iptables-persistent
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
sudo ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6
sudo service iptables restart
sudo service ip6tables restart
```

Remove all old ufw chains references. Edit rules.v* files with your rules.