# Firewall keeps turning on. How do I turn the firewall off permanently?

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, firewall

I have a ubuntu VM running on a mac. This is a test VM and I want to turn off firewall on this VM.
I have run the command

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Isn't this supposed to turn the firewall off until I turn it back on again?
But, the firewall keeps turning itself one again and again see below.
[image: Firewall screenshot]

So, my question is how do I turn the firewall off permanently?

Comment: you could try uninstalling ufw and resetting your iptables as mentioned in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275998/can-i-uninstall-ufw-completely)

Comment: What image do you have posted? The Firewall in the Ubuntu VM, or the Mac Firewall. The two are not related. And... why do you want to turn it off?

Comment: the image is of the firewall in ubuntu, the guest os.

Comment: the image is of the firewall in ubuntu, the guest os.